# Is there a way to keep permanent access to resources exposed with FileProvider across multiple app launches on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

So basically, my app receives external `content://` uris exposed with android [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider). As android documentation states:

> Permissions granted in an Intent remain in effect while the stack of
>   the receiving Activity is active. When the stack finishes, the
>   permissions are automatically removed.

If I want shared resource to be available for my users across multiple app launches I have to copy all it's content to my app's own storage, even if its a big amount of data? (Let's say few gigabytes of photos)

Or do I have some other options to hold permanent access on those uris?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I want shared resource to be available for my users across multiple app launches I have to copy all it's content to my app's own storage, even if its a big amount of data?

Yes.

> Or do I have some other options to hold permanent access on those uris?

No. The only thing that gives you semi-permanent access is if you are using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, then use `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on a `ContentResolver` to request long-term access to the content identified by the `Uri` that you get back.

Alternatively — if you are controlling both sides of this data exchange — do something else for passing the content references. For example, if the content is on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html), just pass the filesystem path, and ensure that both parties have the appropriate permissions.